# mips assembly question

Tags: mips, processor

does anyone know how the CPU determines which register should receive the result produced by an instruction?

anyone???

Answer (score 1):

That would depend on the instruction.  Many instructions take the destination register as an argument, and others have defined behavior as to where a result is stored.  For example, the ADD instruction:

```
add $d, $s, $t
```

The result of $s + $t is stored into $d

[Here is the full reference](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html)

Answer (score 0):

It's encoded in the instruction.  For example, "add" takes dest, op1, op2 and does dest = op1+op2.

See [Wikipedia's page on MIPS architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIPS_architecture#Integer)

Answer (score 0):

For basic instructions like an add or a dub you need to define the register it goes into.  mul and div instructions put values in hi and lo registers.